# gevent-socketio: “cannot import name core”

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, symlink, gevent, gevent-socketio

I have a `Django` project using `gevent-socketio` that runs fine with the manage.py runserver_socketio command in development mode. But I try to deploy it now on a web server (`Apache`) and I get this error:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  92.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py" in process_request
  69.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  551.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  440.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "C:/wamp/www/project\project\urls.py" in <module>
  4. import socketio.sdjango
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\socketio\__init__.py" in <module>
  4. import gevent
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py" in <module>
  40. from gevent import core

Exception Type: ImportError at /project
Exception Value: cannot import name core
```

My additions to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

...

Alias /media/ "C:/wamp/www/project/static"
<Directory C:/wamp/www/project>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/wamp/www/project/mod.wsgi"
```

the mod.wsgi file:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\\wamp\\www\\project")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Versions:

- Django 1.5.2
- Python 2.7.2 (32 bit)
- Apache 2.2.22 (32 bit)
- mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3 (downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so))
- gevent-socketio 0.13.8
- gevent (downloaded from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent))

Apache error log:

```
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 103, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent.greenlet import Greenlet, joinall, killall
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\greenlet.py", line 6, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent.hub import greenlet, getcurrent, get_hub, GreenletExit, Waiter
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\hub.py", line 30, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     greenlet = __import__('greenlet').greenlet
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 103, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent.greenlet import Greenlet, joinall, killall
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\greenlet.py", line 6, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent.hub import greenlet, getcurrent, get_hub, GreenletExit, Waiter
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\hub.py", line 30, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     greenlet = __import__('greenlet').greenlet
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 103, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent import core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ImportError: cannot import name core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 103, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent import core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ImportError: cannot import name core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 92, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\middleware\\common.py", line 69, in process_request
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     resolve(path, urlconf)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent import core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ImportError: cannot import name core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 92, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\middleware\\common.py", line 69, in process_request
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     resolve(path, urlconf)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error]     from gevent import core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:20 2013] [error] ImportError: cannot import name core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 92, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\middleware\\common.py", line 69, in process_request
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     resolve(path, urlconf)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     from gevent import core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error] ImportError: cannot import name core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error] ERROR Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 92, in get_response
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\middleware\\common.py", line 69, in process_request
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     resolve(path, urlconf)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\project\\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     import socketio.sdjango
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent_socketio-0.3.6-py2.7.egg\\socketio\\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     import gevent
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gevent\\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error]     from gevent import core
[Sun Sep 15 01:20:21 2013] [error] ImportError: cannot import name core
```

`Apache` access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2013:01:20:18 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 122971
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2013:01:20:20 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 96545
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2013:01:20:20 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 109064
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2013:01:20:21 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 109064
```

---

**Edit:**

It seems the devs introduced a hacky solution to a problem at the `gevent` library in this file:
https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/5a431f359ca55bb610655b64c7495771671d89ba/setup.py?at=default

The important lines are here:

```
# hack: create a symlink from build/../core.so to gevent/core.so
# to prevent "ImportError: cannot import name core" failures
```

Maybe the problem is the symlink isn't followed somehow. But I checked that everywhere I've added the 'Options FollowSymLinks" and the problem still occurs.

Comment: well.. is there gevent installed on the web server?

Comment: The project is deployed on a local Apache server. So I assume it can use the same installed libraries as before. Do I need to install it again somehow?

Comment: do you use any virtualenvs for both prod and dev?

Comment: no, I don't use virtualenvs

Comment: I did use a symbolic link for my project folder, but that shouldn't matter I guess.

Comment: Can you show us the virtualhost configuration of this app?

Comment: I don't have a virtualhost, but my changes to httpd.conf have been added in the original post

Comment: Upload your Apache error and access logs.

Comment: original post has been updated